# MySQL join get latest valid row

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

users

```
id  |  email
1   |  email1@test.com
2   |  email2@test.com
```

And questions

```
id  |  userId  |  isValid  | status
1   |  1       |  0        | pending
2   |  1       |  1        | processed
```

I want to do a MySQL query that returns all users with the latest valid question (i.e questions.isValid = 1 and questions.id is the highest for that user). I am stumbling on the "latest" part - here is the query so far (which returns all valid questions).

```
SELECT u.email, q.status
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON u.id = q.userId
WHERE q.isValid = 1
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

Any suggestions? There are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find one that precisely matches that problem. Thanks!

EDIT: thanks for all the answers! I forgot to mention one important thing: if there is no valid question for that user, I still want the user to show in the results, with status = ''.

Comment: Quick remark: `LEFT JOIN q .... WHERE q.whatever = 1` practically means `INNER JOIN q ON q.whatever = 1` And an empty fiddle to play with: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77e66

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about sqlfiddle before tonight! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmmkay, what about this?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6d65/1

```
SELECT u.email, q.status
FROM users AS u

LEFT JOIN (

  ( SELECT MAX(mq.id) AS id
    FROM questions AS mq
    WHERE mq.isValid = 1
    GROUP BY mq.userId
  ) AS maxq

  INNER JOIN questions AS q ON q.id = maxq.id

) ON u.id = q.userId

ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

Comment: If this query happens to be slow, check out the other answers too, they also solve your question, just differently. And please DOWNvote me once please, I like round numbers :)

Comment: I'm gonna compare speed between your solution and Mihai's when I have more data in these tables. For the downvote I need just a bit more reputation to get the right ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT u.email, CASE q.status WHEN q.isValid=1 THEN q.status ELSE q.STATUS='' end as status
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN questions AS q ON u.id = q.userId
WHERE  q.id IN(SELECT MAX(id) maxid FROM questions GROUP BY userid)
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/003dd/12

Comment: Thanks for updating to keep users without a valid question. Although now it shows "0" as status instead of its value?

Comment: You said you wanted empty if its not valid.

Comment: OK so I probably got mistaken with all these fiddles open - I thought the 0 was for the valid question and null was for the invalid one in your result but I checked again and it's all good :)

Comment: After testing there are issues with this query as the WHERE clause at the end means that it will be correct only if the latest question is valid - when I need the latest valid question (in the jsfiddle user 1 should have status pending which is the latest valid question).

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like the latest status, this would work:

```
SELECT   u.email,
         (SELECT status FROM questions WHERE userId = u.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) status

FROM     users AS u
```

Answer (score 1):

here your query :

```
SELECT u.email,q.status
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN question AS q ON u.id = q.userId
WHERE  q.id = (SELECT max(id) from question where isvalid = 1 and userid = u.id )
GROUP BY q.isValid,u.id
```

check demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e54a8/1)